# TypeScript: inline null check confusion, not working in particular usage

Tags: typescript, null

Here is a snippet of TypeScript code:

```
if (props.categories && props.categories.length > 0) {
  // code...
}
```

`props.categories` is defined like this:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  categories?: string[];
}
```

I'm a little confused about the `?` operator here...I would think that I could shorten my conditional to:

```
if (props.categories?.length > 0) {
  // code...
}
```

But, TypeScript complains that "*Object is possibly undefined*". Why is this?

Comment: The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: What do you mean by "still" in "still complains"?  I can't reproduce any problem with your first line, as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/mLRX2w).  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/w11kAw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz yep, "still" was the wrong word, thanks for pointing that out, I edited the question. Federkun's answer below cleared up my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props.categories?.length > 0`
may resolve to
`undefined > 0`
which is the origin of the error.
So, it's not strictly the same as `props.categories && props.categories.length > 0`.

My suggestion is to keep it as it is. If you *really really* want to use the optional chaining operator here, you may just need to default to a number to compare

```
props.categories?.length ?? 0 > 0
```

But, this is not any better.